# Adding node to the front of a linked list

Tags: c++

I'm really confused as to what exactly is going on here..

I have the function

```
void addToFront(int data)  
{
  Node* tmp = new Node();
  tmp -> data = data;
  tmp -> next = head;
  head = tmp;
}
```

So when we do the line `tmp-> next = head`, we are making the `tmp` pointer point to what `head` is pointing to (the current first element of the list)? Because that's what it feels like, but wouldn't that just make it point to `head`? And then when we do `head = tmp`, we are making head point to the new node that we created, correct?

Answer (score 15):

This is how your list was (suppose)

```
 +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 |  A |     +-->|     |     +-->|     |      |
 +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 /
```

`Head` is pointing to location `A`.

You make a new node

```
 +----+----+
 | B  |    |
 +----+----+
 /
```

`tmp` now points to `B`. You insert data in `tmp->data`, and then make `tmp -> next = head;`. So now we have:

```
 +----+----+     +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 | B  |next|---->|  A |     +-->|     |     +-->|     |      |
 +----+----+     +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
                  /
```

And then you make`head` to point to `B` instead of `A`.

```
 +----+----+     +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 | B  |next|---->|  A |     +-->|     |     +-->|     |      |
 +----+----+     +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 /  \
```

`head` & `tmp` point to `B` now.

Comment: Here is a complete implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148576/memory-leak-in-removehead-function/19150590#19150590

Answer (score 1):

> So when we do the line tmp-> next =head, we are making the tmp pointer point to what head is pointing to (the current first element of the list)? Because that's what it feels like,

Correct.

> but wouldn't that just make it point to head?

No. To point to head, it would need to contain the *address* of head. But this line makes it contain the *value* of head. So no.

> And then when we do head = tmp, we are making head point to the new node that we created, correct?

Yes.

Comment: @so then since the value of a pointer is the address of the thing it points to, for tmp to get the value of head would mean that it is getting the address of what head points to..

Comment: That's right. `tmp -> next = head;` gives `tmp -> next` and `head` the same value. Thus `tmp -> next` now points to whatever `head` points to.

Comment: but then wouldn't head = tmp mean that head now points to whatever tmp is pointing to? And isn't tmp now pointing to what was formerly the first node on the linked list?

Comment: @FrostyStraw Yes. That's exactly what you want to put a new node at the head of a singly-linked list. That node points to the former head. That node is the new head.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Because tmp is pointing at the new node that was created, so head now has the value of what tmp is pointing to, and is hence pointing to the new node. I thought it was saying that head was getting the value of what the new node was pointing at, and thus was pointing at the second node. I think I get it now though, thank you!

Comment: Right. Since `head` was pointing to the old head, and `tmp -> next` now has the same value `head` had, it points to the old head.

Comment: that also means that tmp is now not pointing at anything? Should we put tmp = nullptr at the end or something?

Comment: @FrostyStraw No the value of tmp hasn't changed. But tmp is just temporary, it's disappears when the function exits, so it doesn't matter what value it has at that point. You could set it to nullptr but it wouldn't do any good (or any harm).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *link;
};
class LinkList
{
    Node *headptr;
public:
    LinkList()
    {
        headptr=NULL;
    }

    void InsertatFirst(int val)
    {
        Node *newNode;
        newNode = new Node;
        newNode ->link =NULL;
        newNode ->data = val;
        newNode ->link=headptr;
        headptr = newNode;
    }

    void Display()
    {
        Node *disNode;
        disNode = headptr;
        while(disNode !=NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Display Node Value is "<<disNode ->data<<endl<<endl;
            disNode =  disNode->link;
        }
    }

};
void main()
{
    LinkList lobj;
    lobj.InsertatFirst(45);
    lobj.InsertatFirst(2);
    lobj.InsertatFirst(1);
    lobj.InsertatFirst(0);
    lobj.InsertatFirst(-1);
    lobj.Display();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
void addToFront(int data) {
  Node* tmp = new Node(t); //assume your Node constructor can handle this
  if(numElements != 0) {   //should check weather empty or not
    x->next = head;        //link them first
    head = x;             //and now make the head point to the new head
  } else {      //if empty you should also set the tail pointer
    head = x;
    tail = x;
  }
  numElements++;
}
```

If there is a head, the new node "next" will be point to the current head which is pointing to another node. and then head=x, the pointer called head is now set to point to the new node rather than the previous one